# Lua: Compare dictionary values and return matching keys & shared value

Tags: dictionary, lua, compare

I've created a dictionary of key:value pairs consisting of names and IP address info and I need to look for names that have duplicate IPs and return the names (Keys) that match with the IP address info (Values) they share.

The dictionary "t" would consist of:

> adam,192.168.1.1
>
> bob,192.168.1.2
>
> claire,192.168.1.2
>
> deb,192.168.1.3
>
> edgar,192.168.1.1

I need to find the duplicates and return a result along the lines of:

> adam and edgar are both using 192.168.1.1
>
> bob and claire are both using 192.168.1.2

I'm not sure how to iterate through dictionary keys by name.  When I'd originally posed the question, I'd provided a code sample (un-working) were I was attempting to do it by index location.  I've since deleted that and am open to suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the table you've built is the one you need. Try printing the contents of `t`.

Comment: removed my bad table insertion code.  It was distracting from the question I was actually trying to ask.  Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
t={
    ["adam"]= "192.168.1.1",
    ["bob"]= "192.168.1.2",
    ["claire"]= "192.168.1.2",
    ["deb"]= "192.168.1.3",
    ["edgar"]= "192.168.1.1",
}

local d={}
for k,v in pairs(t) do
    if d[v]~=nil then
        io.write(k," and ",d[v]," are both using ",v,"\n")
    else
        d[v]=k
    end
end
```

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks you :)   It didn't work the first time in the console, but did when I removed local from "local d={}"

Comment: @fbonds66, instead of trying it in the console, you can also try it in the [Lua live demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html).